# NSViewController window not resizing and not closing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I added NSTableView to NSViewController.view, and setting the setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to No,  unable to resize the window height anymore from code or debugging the app and trying to modify window height by dragging the edge of the window, i am only able to modify the width.
in ViewDidLoad I have:

[super viewDidLoad];

```
NSView* firstView = [self view];

tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] init];
[firstView addSubview:tableView];

[tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[tableView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:firstView.heightAnchor multiplier:0.9].active = YES;
[tableView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:firstView.widthAnchor multiplier:0.9].active = YES;


NSTableColumn * column1 = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Id"];
NSTableColumn * column2 = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Name"];
[column1 setWidth:250];
[column2 setWidth:250];
// generally you want to add at least one column to the table view.
[tableView addTableColumn:column1];
[tableView addTableColumn:column2];
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];

[[tableView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:firstView.centerYAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
[[tableView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:firstView.centerXAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
```

Comment: One suggestion: don't turn off the container (`[self view]`) view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property . The top container view is managed by Cocoa and you shouldn't fiddle with how it gets sized/resized.

Comment: Another suggestion: `NSTableView` does *not* like to used as a standalone view, and it can be a nightmare trying to get it to behave itself. Wrap it in an `NSScrollView` and see if that improves the situation.

Comment: NSScrollView solved it.